# How do I resolve multi-part identifier errors

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am unable to figure out the issue with the following query:

```sql
select distinct  
    i.Supplr1, v.Name, s.InvtID, s.CuryCost, s.CurySlsPrice, s.OrdNbr,
    Sum(s.CurySlsPrice - s.CuryCost) AS GrossProfit,
    Sum((s.CurySlsPrice - s.CuryCost)/s.CurySlsPrice) AS GrossPer
from
    SOLine s, Inventory i, Vendor v
Inner Join 
    Inventory on Inventory.InvtID = s.InvtID
Inner join 
    Vendor on Vendor.VendID = Inventory.Supplr1

Union All

select distinct  
    a.InvtID, s.OrdNbr, s.OrdNbr, s.CuryCost, s.CurySlsPrice, s.OrdNbr,    
    s.Status, a.PerPost
from 
    ARTran a, Inventory i, SOLine S 
Inner join 
    Inventory on Inventory.InvtId = ARTran.InvtID
Inner join 
    ARTran on ARTran.OrdNbr = SOLine.OrdNbr
```

The errors are as follows:

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 20
> The multi-part identifier "s.InvtID" could not be bound.
>
> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 31
> The multi-part identifier "ARTran.InvtID" could not be bound.
>
> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 33
> The multi-part identifier "SOLine.OrdNbr" could not be bound.

I have tried everything I know (my brain may be a little foggy) yet continue to get the errors.

What is the issue with my query?

Comment: Could you please post the table schemas of `SOLine` and `ARTran`.

Comment: **WHY** are you using the three tables both in the comma-separated list in the `FROM` clause (this is **discouraged** and should be avoided!), as well as with the proper `JOIN` statements? The proper `JOIN`s should be used - and they should get table aliases `JOIN Inventory i ON i.InvtID = s.InvtID`. If you clean up your query like that, it should work fine

Comment: Why are you mixing `join` syntax with 30+ year old syntax? you are repeating tables and this is your issue.

Comment: is this complete query. I see line numbers 31, 33, which dont exist in your code

Comment: Explicit JOIN's are evaluated _before_ comma separated, implicit ones. This means that `Vendor v
Inner Join Inventory` can only reference v and Inventory columns in the `ON` clause.

Answer (score 3):

You should clean up your query to something like this:

- use **only** the proper `JOIN` syntax - get rid of that old, crappy "comma-separated list of tables" in the `FROM` clause!
- use table alias on the joined tables

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    i.Supplr1, v.Name, s.InvtID, s.CuryCost, s.CurySlsPrice, s.OrdNbr,
    SUM(s.CurySlsPrice - s.CuryCost) AS GrossProfit,
    SUM((s.CurySlsPrice - s.CuryCost)/s.CurySlsPrice) AS GrossPer
FROM
    SOLine s
INNER JOIN 
    Inventory i ON i.InvtID = s.InvtID
INNER JOIN 
    Vendor v ON v.VendID = i.Supplr1
GROUP BY
    i.Supplr1, v.Name, s.InvtID, s.CuryCost, s.CurySlsPrice, s.OrdNbr

UNION ALL

SELECT DISTINCT  
    a.InvtID, s.OrdNbr, s.OrdNbr, s.CuryCost, s.CurySlsPrice, s.OrdNbr,    
    s.Status, a.PerPost
FROM 
    SOLine s
INNER JOIN 
    Inventory i ON i.InvtId = a.InvtID
INNER JOIN 
    ARTran a ON a.OrdNbr = s.OrdNbr
```

Comment: If you're going to clean up the code, DISTINCT serves no useful purpose in the first query and it needs a GROUP BY clause for summing.

Comment: @SMor: thanks - you're absolutely right - I've updated my response, and added the `GROUP BY` - time to remove the downvote :-)

Answer (score 0):

The columns you're SELECTing don't exist. Check your database schema